# How to set option style in css?

Tags: css, select, font-family

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internet Explorer: drop down does not display option font family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938467/internet-explorer-drop-down-does-not-display-option-font-family)

I would like to modify the select's font family. Unfourtunatly it works only in firefox:

```
<select>
 <option value="times" style="font-family: times;">Times</option>
 <option value="arial" style="font-family: arial;">Arial</option>
 <option value="garamond" style="font-family: garamond;">Garamond</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible or cross-browser compatible using pure HTML/CSS. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rttKT/) for an example. This is due to the fact that some HTML elements cannot be styled. However, you can accomplish this using Javascript.